Performance improvement using Loop controller
Do we see any performance related changes when we use Loop controller in Jmeter and when we are not using it ?
I have API testing with Jmeter and I can see some changes in response time when I use Loop controller and when I dont use Loop controller. I am using Infinite option inside loop controller so that it will run for 1 hour without any number of loops.
CSV data set config is inside the loop controller only so that it will take different data for each time.

Loop Controller per se doesn't have any impact on the system under test performance, it just controls for how many times its children will be executed.
It might be the case you're creating different workload models with and without the Loop Controller.
JMeter acts as follows:

JMeter starts threads according to ramp-up period defined in the Thread Group
Once started a thread begins executing Samplers upside down (or according to the Logic Controllers)
When there are no more Samplers to execute and loops to iterate the thread is being shut down
When the last thread is shut down the test ends

So if you don't have the Loop Controller in place it might be the case that threads finish their job and stop so the actual concurrency is lower and hence response time is lower. And with the Loop Controller the threads are running until you stop the test providing higher concurrency and higher response time. You can use a Listener like Active Threads Over Time or the relevant chart of the HTML Reporting Dashboard to check what's really going on in cases when you have and don't have the Loop Controller.
